# How can I check several exceptions with Guava makeChecked?

Tags: java, android, guava

How can I check several exceptions with Guava makeChecked?

For example i need check IOException and my custom exception MyException?

Comment: I think in this case you would either need to wrap the `IOException` in a `MyException`, or check on the common ancestor in the `Exception` hierarchy (possibly `Exception`).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the method signature and generic type parameters for [Futures#makeChecked](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/CheckedFuture.html) it's impossible. One checked exception or the highway.

Comment: orien this question is about makeChecked method from Google Guava. And Im not using Java 7 since Android doesn't support it.

Comment: May be it is possible to chain makeChecked calls. In .NET Rx extensions Catch method is chainable.